# Plugin.ImageResourceName doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: ocean

It would be great if the Petrel Plugin Manager could display our custom bitmap for each of our plugins - however, the `Plugin.ImageResourceName` property doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
   public override string ImageResourceName { get { return "Blueback.Toolbox.Plugin.Toolbox.png"; } }
```

The image is embedded correctly (according to the documentation and ILDisAsm) - but Plugin Manager insists on using the generic image instead.  Are there undocumented requirements on dimensions or format?  The code snippets in the documentation mention both bmp and png, without demonstrating that the property actually works.

I haven't been able to locate an actual running sample in the SDK (only Module samples) nor in the code sample downloads (several Plugins here, but they return null for the resource name).

Can anyone provide a working sample or the missing key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image provided via Plugin.ImageResourceName is displayed in the Petrel License Dialog, and you are right, it is not displayed in Plugin Manager as it always uses the generic image to represent plugins. We will consider changing it in Petrel 2013.1.